# Pass authorization from Blazor Server to .NET Core via SignalR

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have an SignalR connection between Blazor Server and  .NET Core. In Blazor I have authentication on Auth0 and get token and all needed claims. My authorization with roles work on Blazor with tags but not work then I pass it to .NET Core

This code works fine in Blazor

```html
<AuthorizeView Roles="admin, Superuser">
    <p>You can only see this if you're an Admin or Superuser.</p>
</AuthorizeView>


<AuthorizeView Roles="participant">
    <p>You can only see this if you're an participant.</p>
</AuthorizeView>

<AuthorizeView Roles="user">
    <p>You can only see this if you're an user.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Here's part of my controller:

```cs
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:7277/users", options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(tokenString);
        })
    .WithHeaders()
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

hubConnection.On<List<User>>("ReceiveGetAll", async (users) =>
{
    messages = users;
    isLoaded = true;
});

await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("GetAll");
```

Here's part of my hub (with generics)

```cs
[HubMethodName("GetAll")]
[Authorize]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GetAll()
{
    var context = _contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    context.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    var dtoItems = await _context.Set<Tmodel>()
        .IncludeVirtualProperties(new Tmodel { })
        .Select(e => e.ConvertToDto<Tmodel, TmodelDTO>())
        .ToListAsync();

    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReceiveGetAll", dtoItems);
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MsSqlAccessor.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MsSqlAccessor.Hubs;
using MsSqlAccessor.DbControllers;
using MsSqlAccessor.Services;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace MsSqlAccessor
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
                // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        // If the request is for our hub...
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        /*                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                                    (path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/chat")))*/
                        {
                            // Read the token out of the query string
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });


            builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            });
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CompetitionBdTestContext>();

            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            //builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opt =>
            {
                opt.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyAPI", Version = "v1" });
                opt.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Please enter token",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    Scheme = "bearer"
                });
                opt.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                    {
                        {
                            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id="Bearer"
                                }
                            },
                            new string[]{}
                        }
                });
            });

            //builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserRole, MockUserRole>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<EventsDbController>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();


            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: default,
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                //endpoints.MapHub<UserHub>("/users");
            });

            //app.MapHub<UserHub>("/users");
            //app.MapHub<MssqlHubOld<User>>("/users");
            //app.MapHub<EventParticipantTeamHub>("/eventparticipantteams");
            app.MapHub<EventHub>("/events");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<EventManager, EventManagerDTO>>("/EventManagers");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<EventParticipantTeam, EventParticipantTeamDTO>>("/eventparticipantteams");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<EventTask, EventTaskDTO>>("/EventTasks");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<EventTaskEvaluateUser, EventTaskEvaluateUserDTO>>("/EventTaskEvaluateUsers");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<Role, RoleDTO>>("/Roles");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<Status, StatusDTO>>("/Statuses");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<MsSqlAccessor.Models.Task, TaskDTO>>("/Tasks");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<TaskCategory, TaskCategoryDTO>>("/TaskCategories");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<TaskParticipant, TaskParticipantDTO>>("/TaskParticipants");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<Team, TeamDTO>>("/Teams");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<TeamTask, TeamTaskDTO>>("/TeamTasks");
            app.MapHub<MsSQLHub<User, UserDTO>>("/Users");

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new ErrorHandlingPipelineModule());
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying get token on

```cs
AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
```

and in Hub like

```cs
var context = _contextAccessor.HttpContext;
context.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

But anything was failed. Tell me please how i can receive authorization on .Net Core?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are requesting the token inside your Hub-method. You shouldn´t need to do that (and you are not doing anything with it from what I see) - authorization is already taken care of before you end up in the Authorized method, 

I assume you looked at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#identity-server-jwt-authentication
:: I don't know how to setup Auth0 but you might get clues from in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#identity-server-jwt-authentication

Comment: I cant see how you get the token in the hubconnection. I assume you inject ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, and set token = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "scope" });  Do you get a valid token there?